# How to understand session and flash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, sails.js

I am learnning Sails.js.
There are some codes confused me.

```js
if(err) {
  console.log(err);
  req.session.flash = {
    err: err
  }
  
  return res.redirect('/user/new');
}
```

Is flash the part of session?

Comment: It is my first question in Stack Overflow.Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flash is part of the session. It is just data that is marked to be deleted after you look at it.

Other MVC frameworks have similar features. Here is what [Catalyst has to say about it](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Plugin::Session#flash):

> Note that use of the flash is an easy way to get data across requests, but it's also strongly disrecommended, due it it being inherently plagued with race conditions. This means that it's unlikely to work well if your users have multiple tabs open at once, or if your site does a lot of AJAX requests.